# Proper import pattern for pipeable RxJs operators using Angular CLI/WebPack rollup

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, rxjs

In Angular CLI versions <1.5.0 you could import your project's RxJs operators into a single file and use them throughout the application.

i.e.

*rxjs-operators.ts*

```
// Statics
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/range';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/concat';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';

// Operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
...
```

*app.module.ts*

```
// OPERATORS
import './rxjs-operators';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [...],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

With the encouraged usage of the RxJs `pipe` operator the import examples are always within the individual module it's used in.

i.e.

```
...
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/util/pipe';
import { take, catchError  } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class AccountDetailsResolver implements Resolve<AccountDetails> {
  constructor(private membersApi: MembersApiService,
              private router: Router,
              private navigationManager: NavigationManagerService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<AccountDetails> {
    if(route.paramMap.get('accountId')) {
      return this.membersApi.getBasicDetails(route.paramMap.get('accountId')).pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          this.navigationManager.navigateToDefaultScreen();
          return Observable.of(null);
        }),
        take(1)
      );
    } else {
      return Observable.of(null);
    }
  }
}
```

---

I'm wondering if there's still a way to import all of these operators and static methods into one place or if it's necessary to include the import into each Angular definition for the `Module`, `Component`, `Service`, `Pipe`, `Directive`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Members from the Angular CLI team [replied](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8854) and said that since the pipeable operators are functions they need to be imported into each file.

**Upside:** The application supports better tree-shaking leading to a smaller bundle size. Third party libraries won't dirty the Observable prototype. It also becomes much easier to create custom operators.

**Downside:** The operators used by the application need to be included on a per file basis instead of once for the entire app.